# .NET Text not replacing when saved with savedialog + newline saving

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Im working on my project and i have two problems that i cant fix, tried to find on google and tried to fix it by myself but no luck

***Problem #1***

When i try to save text from richtextbox(multiline) and replace it with existing text file it dont replace file, it just add new text to old one.*(Sorry for terrible English i will make example bellow so you can get it)*

Textbox text:

```
NEWinformation1
NEWinformation2
Newinformation3
NEWinformation4
NEWinformation5
```

Old txt file that already exists:

```
OLDinformation1
OLDinformation2
OLDinformation3
OLDinformation4
OLDinformation5
```

And what i get when try to replace existing text file:

```
NEWinformation1
NEWinformation2
Newinformation3
NEWinformation4
NEWinformation5
OLDinformation1
OLDinformation2
OLDinformation3
OLDinformation4
OLDinformation5
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim Save As New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim myStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Save.Filter = "Text *.txt|*.txt"
    Save.CheckPathExists = True
    Save.Title = "Save File"
    Save.ShowDialog(Me)
        Try
            myStreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(Save.FileName)
            myStreamWriter.Write(RTBOutput.Text)
            myStreamWriter.Flush()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Problem #2

Text i get in richtextbox is scraped from my server (www.example.com/information.txt)
Problem is there when i save my multi lined text from server, regular notepad reads it all in one line, but when use notepad++ and enable "Show all charachters" in np++ settings it reads evry line separately but with **LF** newline type code instead of **CR LF**

Here is pic:

[image]

This code i use for scraping text from server:

```
   Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(SERVERADDRESS))
        RTBOutput.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
        LabelLineCount.Text = RTBOutput.Lines.Count
```

Comment: Don't understand. You complain that AppendText appends text?

Comment: @Steve Thank you, its my fault. Replaced AppendText with CreateText and now works fine. But still have problem with **LF** line break

Comment: You can use `reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: I used it in bgworker like this
`Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(ADDRESS))
            RTBoxShop.Text = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: And it just give me blank output @JakubDąbek

Comment: It is better to split this question into two different posts, or modify it in order to leave only the remaining (unanswered) question. Multiple questions asked in one post cannot have a good answer.

Comment: Hi Uranus, Sorry for not updating my post.
I was too busy to modify it, i found answers for both question sadly not from this post

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1

```
Dim Save As New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim myStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Save.Filter = "Text *.txt|*.txt"
    Save.CheckPathExists = True
    Save.Title = "Save File"
    Save.ShowDialog(Me)
        Try
            myStreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(Save.FileName) ''<-- Here is my fault
            myStreamWriter.Write(RTBOutput.Text)
            myStreamWriter.Flush()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Replaced AppendText with CreateText:

```
myStreamWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(Save.FileName)
```

Answer #2

Resloved that problem with next code:

```
    Dim Save As New SaveFileDialog()
        Save.Filter = "Text *.txt|*.txt"
        Save.CheckPathExists = True
        Save.Title = "Save File"
        Save.ShowDialog(Me)
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(Save.FileName)
                For Each line As String In RTBoxShop.Lines
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                Next
            End Using
```